# Test a function passed as an argument to other function in Angular code using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is sample snippet code. 
I have a service **Myservice** where I have **myfunction**, when the promise is rejected I catch the error and call errorPopup which again calls a function **ShowApiError** in service **popUpservice**. which accepts a function **userOkayedCallback** as parameter

In this function I have done an assignment of url to window.location.href.

**My question: How can I unit test this assignment in jasmine?**

```
 function somefunction(){
     Myservice.myfunction(vm.arg).then(function(){
       //some code here
    },


    function (error) {
             errorPopup(error);
        });
    }


    function errorPopup(){
    popupService.showApiError(userOkayedCallback, error.status);
    }

    function userOkayedCallback(){
        $window.location.href = vm.url                   
    }}
```

Comment: is `Myservice.myfunction` using $http or $resource?

Comment: it is using $http

Answer (score 1):

```
describe('spec', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('popupService', {
        'showApiError': userOkayedCallback => userOkayedCallback()
      });
      $provide.value('$window', {
        location: {href: ''}
      });
    });
  });

  it('should relocate the user', function() {
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'url/to/service').respond(500, []);
    Myservice.myfunction();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($window.location.href).toBe('something');
  });
});
```

This is not a working example, but you get the idea. Mock the popupservice and with a function that just executes the callback, then fail the service call with $httpBackend and check if window.href is the correct value.

For the code below to work you need to inject the depencendies.